# How to speed up matplotlib savefig()?

Tags: python, performance, matplotlib

I use matplotlib to generate lots of figures and use savefig() to save the png files to disks.The problem is that the speed of savefig() is not fast enough. Just want to know any tip of speeding up png-file generation, such as using GPU, savefig() alternative function etc. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using an interactive backend? When saving many files to disk it is faster to use a non-interactive backend (e.g. `Agg`).